# How to use proxy and ignore specific request ssl errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

Good day, I am trying to connect to a third party rest API which is kinda old and has its certificate expired. I am using `NodeJS` and `axios` for sending request which at the moment looks something like this.

```
agent = new HttpsProxyAgent({ host, port, auth: `${uname}:${pass}` });

this.client = axios.create({
    baseURL: this.baseUrl,
    headers: this.headers,
    httpsAgent: agent,
});
```

the `agent` above creates a proxy agent so my request would tunnel through that host which i am later mounting on axios, i am using this package `https-proxy-agent`. Now the proxy works fine and all, but it throws an error `certificate has expired`. I have tried to use `rejectUnauthorized: false` but that didn't work at all, however i found one more solution and that is to use `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`. But it is widely described as dangerous to use on the server, i also wonder if i will use this environment variable would it make client requests visible when intercepting?

What i need here is to just connect to the proxy and reject certificate errors only for this axios client, if there are solutions for other http clients feel free to share, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue with a different package.

```
import { getProxyHttpAgent } from 'proxy-http-agent';


const proxyUrl = `http://${host}:${port}`;

agent = getProxyHttpAgent({
    proxy: proxyUrl,
    endServerProtocol: 'https:',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
});
```

setting agent with this package works great, except for some reason i have to use non authentication based proxy otherwise it would throw some weird ssl error which looks like this

`tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 20920:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:`.